# Trying to create a function with .split, but getting "split is not a function"

Tags: javascript, split

**My problem:**

I'm trying to create a function using the split but I'm getting error

**My code:**

```
this.sendkeys_foreach = function (variable, locator) {

    var variableToSplit = variable;
    variableToSplit.split('').forEach((c) => locator.sendKeys(c));
};
```

Calling the function:

```
this.rut = element.all(by.name('rut')).first();
var rut = casual.numerify(randomRut);

this.sendkeys_foreach(rut, this.rut);
```

**My error**

```
- Failed: variableToSplit.split is not a function
```

Comment: This suggests that variableToSplit is not a string. Can you determine what value it has?

Answer (score 0):

2 Things:

1. `.split('')` exists on the `String.prototype` object. One of its primary uses is to create an array that can be iterated over. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split
2. If you see `variableToSplit.split is not a function` in your console or similar type error when using a method on a prototype it will generally mean that you are incorrectly using that method.  You could be using `.split('')` on an object, or even more likely, you are using `.split('')` on an array.  For example, `[1,2,3].split('')` returns the exact error that you posted in console.

I would try to review the input.  In your case it is `variable`.  With that error it might be possible to simply iterate over the collection without calling `.split('')` at all.